# Is there a means to disassociate shipping addresses with the billing account in magento?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, magento

I am working on a site for a client where purchases are always sent to a third party in Magento CE ver. 1.8.1.0. While doing some style edits, we ran into a deeper issue; all of the shipping addresses are anchored to the account that created the billing information. The initial problem became apparent when dealing with shipping address pre-population in onepage checkout, where shipping was defaulting to the billing address (when tracing the methods calling the name). We could resolve this part on the frontend by repopulating the fields (or depopulating them) with javascript/ajax, however this will still leave an administrative nightmare unresolved on the back end, which will need to be addressed for the clients business model to work as intended. Basically, we need to disassociate the shipping addresses completely with the billing account and assign independent addresses to each purchase rather than keeping them all tied to the origin account, so when whoever is administrating the site has to deal with ongoing business concerns, they don't have to sort through a billion addresses in admin >> customers >> (account) >> addresses to deal with customer issues. Is there any extension that can easily accomplish this, or alternately some hidden core functionality to do so? Writing a custom solution will be difficult on the budget.

Comment: check out http://nikunjvadariya.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/magento-how-to-rewriteoverride-customer-address-abstract/

Comment: actually this is a better solution http://optimiseblog.co.uk/magento-checkout-ship-to-this-address/